# How can i remove required field validation on click submit button?

Tags: forms

I have some radio buttons such as draft, need review, etc. I want to remove (omit) the required fields when draft is selected, and click on the submission button.
I tried with below code but it is not working.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
 if($form_id =='catalog_node_form')
 {
  $form['#validate'][] ='remove_required_field';
 } 
} 

function remove_required_field($element)
{ 
 foreach (element_children($element) as $name) 
 { 
  $element[$name]['#required'] = FALSE; 
 } 
 return $element; 
}
```

Comment: simple solution is  dont mark the field as required.

Comment: *["If the question is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question."](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*

Comment: Add your code to the question body rather than adding that as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In the form_alter function you can use the limit_validation_errors property.

```
'#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
```

The above code will not perform any field validations. You can then add the individual fields that you need to validate here using the below code.

```
$form['actions']['next']['#limit_validation_errors'][] = array($field_key);
```

Where next is the action that I am using.

Comment: Good way, but possibly a bit overcomplicated.

Comment: True. It may be a little over-complicated. I wanted the control as I was building a multi-step registration form and hence it made sense in my case :)

Comment: Yea, if you want to leave evaluation to the original module, your way is better than mine. But if original module only sets `#required`, my way is simpler. So, it all depends on use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is caused by the fact that #required is resolved before custom validation handlers. Thus, when `remove_required_field()` is called, it's already too late.

Instead, un your `mymodule_form_alter()` hook set:

```
$element[$name]['#required'] = FALSE; 
$form['#validate'][] ='function_that_will_test_checkbox_only_if_its_needed';
```